# SQL How to return a result set that will combine multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I am trying to get one row returned for each store number and per date that includes all values from the RecordTypeA column for that date.

The table I am using is created with a column named "RecordTypeA", it is a bit data type with (1 and 0) entries.  1 equals Type A and 0 equals Type B.

What I am trying to do is show the value of the RecordTypeA column for the store if there are entries of 1 and / or 0 on the same date on the same row.

**Scenario 1 (One row returns for the store for the date):**    RecordTypeA column value = '1'
There is one row in the table for the store and date and the RecordTypeA column = '1' :

**Scenario 2 (Two Rows return for the store for the same date):**

Row One - RecordTypeA = '1'
Row Two - RecordTypeA = '0'  (The column is still named RecordTypeA, but value '0' means something different so I want to create a column name?)

**Scenario 3 (One row returns for the store for the date):**
RecordTypeA column value = '0'
There is one row in the table for the store and date and the RecordTypeA column = '0' :

My issue is that I am getting multiple rows returned when the store has a RecordtypeA = 0 and a RecordtypeA = 1 row. Which I need to return on the same row. (Create columns that hold both 1 and 0 or Null.

What I am getting is

### StoreID      Date                RecordTypeA

1234        2020-01-04          0

1234        2020-01-05          0

1234        2020-01-05          1

Needed:

### StoreID      Date              RecordTypeA         RecordTypeB

1234        2020-01-04            0                   NULL

1234        2020-01-05            0                 1

I have tried adding in case statements but I have not been able to get the one row as needed. Also, searched and tried PIVOT statements (I don't truly understand PIVOTs) but I get an error on the RecordTypeA Bit type.

Case when s.RecordTypeA = '1' Then 'TypeA' Else 'Null' End as Type
Case when s.RecordTypeA = '0' Then 'TypeB' Else 'Null' End as Type

```
SELECT r.StoreID,
r.CreatedDate,
s.RecordTypeA
From Request r
Inner Join Stores s on r.id = s.id
Group by r.StoreID,
r.CreatedDate,
s.RecordTypeA
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow community!

Have you tried to construct 3 queries and use `UNION ALL` statement?

You can create a query for `StoreID, Date, RecordTypeA, TypeB` and `Typec`.

For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(r.StoreID, r.CreatedDate, s.RecordTypeA) AS DATA, 'A' AS TYPE
FROM YOURDATABASE.YOURTABLE
WHERE (A CRITERIA FOR TYPE A)

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT(r.StoreID, r.CreatedDate, s.RecordTypeA) AS DATA, 'B' AS TYPE
FROM YOURDATABASE.YOURTABLE
WHERE (A CRITERIA FOR TYPE B)

UNION ALL

...
```

I use the same alias on the example because with union all, all the queries must have the same columns, so you can use a CONCAT to put all your data from the different queries in one column, the column "TYPE" is for the difference the queries at the result.

Even if you not use concat you can return the columns different **but** all the queries must have the same column count on the select.

With multiple queries, you can define de criteria you want for type A, B, C through Z but have all of them at one result.

**Important**: `Union all` statements are somehow heavy for performance, so have it in mind.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the response. That doesn't seem to work in this situation I still don't get the store, date and both record types on the one row. I get two rows for the store, one with Type A and one Type B.

Comment: It's ok, I hope you find the solution soon.